# Unexpected key in dagger compilation

Tags: dependency-injection, dagger

I get the following error from dagger:

```
[ERROR] error on execute: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected key: ca.nanometrics.apollo.instrument.configuration.ResourceOwnerController<>
```

I believe this happens because I have a class with no injectable dependencies - it has an empty public constructor (with @Inject), with nothing to inject in members either.  I did this to not have to declare the @Provides for it.   Note that the class with the @Inject is a subclass of the class listed in the error message above:

```
public class ResourceOwnerControllerHelios extends ResourceOwnerController<ResourceOwnerFactoryHelios>
{

  @Inject
  public ResourceOwnerControllerHelios()
  {
    // do nothing
  }
```

Is this a bug in dagger, or is there something I am missing?

If I remove the @Inject and still don't add the @Provides to the module, it of course doesn't work at all, since dagger needs @Inject or @Provides on all dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Oi - this looks like its' bumping into a mishandling of generics. :/  Maybe file an issue on github.  What you're doing should work - that is, adding @Inject to a no-args public constructor.  I believe Dagger is trying to climb the inheritance hierarchy and not handling the generics in the parent.  We should be handling this case.